# Making ajax call using redux-saga and updating store

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

im new to whole React env and im trying to create a GET request to Google Api using redux-saga library.

Im sort of missing 2 things. First problem is that my saga function is called again and again forever ( have no idea why ).

The second thing is how to pass the data properly to the reducer.

Here is my Saga:

```
function* watchAutoCompleteFetch() {
  yield takeLatest(UPDATE_ZIP_AUTOCOMPLETE, requestAutoComplete);
}

function requestAutoCompleteApi() {
  return fetch(
    'some-url-here'
  ).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => json)
  .catch((e) => {
    put({type: "AUTOCOMPLETE_ZIP_FETCH_FAILED", message: e.message});
  });
}

function* requestAutoComplete() {
  const data = call(requestAutoCompleteApi);
  yield put(updateZipAutoCompleteAction(data));
}
```

And reducer function:

```
const updateZipAutoComplete = (state, data) => {
  debugger;
  return state;
};
```

In reducer, I get the data as some sort of call object from the redux-saga, not a promise, nor the data.

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like I was missing a yield statement. The function is called forever anyway, is it expected behavior or not?

Comment: Ok, found out an issue, will post answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

So, turns out there was indeed 2 problems. One is that I was missing yield keyword, the second was I was calling always the same reducer, which triggered the dispatch event again and it went into loop and run forever.

The actual solutions looks like this:

```
function* watchAutoCompleteFetch() {
  yield takeLatest(UPDATE_ZIP_AUTOCOMPLETE, requestAutoComplete);
}

function requestAutoCompleteApi() {
  return fetch(
    'some-url-here'
  ).then((response) => response.json())
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e)
  });
}

function* requestAutoComplete() {
  const data = yield call(requestAutoCompleteApi);
  if(data.status ==="OK") {
    yield put(updateZipAutoCompleteSucceedAction(data));
  } else {
    yield put(updateZipAutoCompleteFailedAction(data));
  }
}
```